# How to $watch changes on models created by ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Consider [this Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/T5h63NGdhJMgmx40N45R?p=preview) for example. I don't know how many members of `fooCollection` will be created beforehand. So I don't know how many `bar` models are going to exist.

But I know they are going to be angular models, and I know where they are going to be.

How do I do a `$watch` on these?

I need to do that because I need to trigger behavior when a `bar` model is changed. Watching the fooCollection itself is not enough, the `$watch` listener does not fire when a `bar` is changed.

Relevant html:

```
<body ng-controller="testCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="(fooKey, foo) in fooCollection">
    Tell me your name: <input ng-model="foo.bar">
    <br />
    Hello, my name is {{ foo.bar }}
  </div>
  <button ng-click="fooCollection.push([])">Add a Namer</button>
</body>
```

Relevant JS:

```
angular
.module('testApp', [])
.controller('testCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.fooCollection = [];

  $scope.$watch('fooCollection', function (oldValue, newValue) {
    if (newValue != oldValue)
      console.log(oldValue, newValue);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Create individual list-item controllers: [demo on Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/2Z1LjPDAiUfKPlQp9BjS?p=preview)

### js

```
angular
  .module('testApp', [])
  .controller('testCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.fooCollection = [];
  })
  .controller('fooCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.$watch('foo.bar', function (newValue, oldValue) {
      console.log('watch fired, new value: ' + newValue);
    });
  });
```

### HTML

```
<html ng-app="testApp">
  <body ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="(fooKey, foo) in fooCollection" ng-controller="fooCtrl">
      Tell me your name: <input ng-model="foo.bar" ng-change="doSomething()">
      <br />
      Hello, my name is {{ foo.bar }}
    </div>
    <button ng-click="fooCollection.push([])">Add a Namer</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow. I need to think more in terms of controllers being first-class citizens in angular, for attaching behavior to *any* scope.

Comment: Just a comment to remind users to NEVER link *only* to an external website. You **must** give the code in the answer body. I have the same problem as OP, an plnkr link is down, so this answer is useless :(

Comment: This does not answer the original question: how to put a watch on items in a ng-repeat collection. What would be the $watch code in this nested controller?

Comment: Copied the relevant code from the plunkr so answers become useful again ;-).

Comment: Could someone please explain why two controllers are needed?

Answer (score 9):

If you have your collection populated, you can place a watch on each item of the ng-repeat:

**html**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
   {{ item.itemField }}
</div>
```

**js**

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
   $scope.$watch('items[' + i + ']', function (newValue, oldValue) {
      console.log(newValue.itemField + ":::" + oldValue.itemField);
   }, true);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can pass true as third argument into $watch

```
$scope.$watch('something', function() { doSomething(); }, true);
```

[https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope)

Answer (score 3):

You can also create a custom directive that will tell your main controller for the changes

```
YourModule.directive("batchWatch",[function(){
return {
    scope:"=",
    replace:false,
    link:function($scope,$element,$attrs,Controller){
        $scope.$watch('h',function(newVal,oldVal){
            if(newVal !== oldVal){
              Controller.updateChange(newVal,oldVal,$scope.$parent.$index);
            }

        },true);

    },
    controller:"yourController"
};
}]);
```

assume your markup is like this

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="h in complicatedArrayOfObjects">
      <input type="text" ng-model="someModel" batch-watch="$index" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

and this is your controller

```
YourModule.controller("yourController",[$scope,function($scope){
    this.updateChange = function(newVal,oldVal,indexChanged){
      console.log("Details about the change");
    }
}]);
```

You can also play around the value provided by the directive link function which sits on first 3 arguments, scope,element and attr.

Answer (score 2):

Since I didn't want another controller I ended up using [ng-change](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) instead.

Simple jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/maistho/z0xazw5n/

Relevant HTML:

```
<body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="foo in fooCollection">Tell me your name:
        <input ng-model="foo.bar" ng-change="fooChanged(foo)">
        <br />Hello, my name is {{foo.bar}}</div>
    <button ng-click="fooCollection.push({})">Add a Namer</button>
</body>
```

Relevant JS:

```
angular.module('testApp', [])
    .controller('testCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.fooCollection = [];

    $scope.fooChanged = function (foo) {
        console.log('foo.bar changed, new value of foo.bar is: ', foo.bar);
    };
});
```

Comment: I think ng-change is better solution than add a nested controller.

Comment: ng-change is neat, simple, clear.   Adding a nested controller is complex, unneccessary

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this

```
 <div ng-repeat="foo in fooCollection" ng-click="select(foo)">Tell me your ame:
        <input ng-model="foo.bar" ng-change="fooChanged(foo)">
        <br />Hello, my name is {{foo.bar}}</div>
        <button ng-click="fooCollection.push({})">Add a Namer</button>
 </div>
```

There is the code in Directive/Controller

```
 $scope.selectedfoo = {};
 $scope.select = (foo) => {
    $scope.selectedfoo = foo;
 }

 $scope.$watch('selectedfoo ', (newVal, oldVal) => {
  if (newVal) {

  }
 },true)
```