# how can I use ng-change inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to execute a function inside ng-change every time a check box is clicked.**I need to get the value of model or somehow know which check box was clicked so that I can call another corresponding function for the checked value and also when when that checkbox was unclicked so that I can hode some values**

not sure if the approach I am using is correct but this is my code:
[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/sqs7kApZH21W1GsVJPBz?p=preview)

HTML

```
 <input type="checkbox" ng-model="data.model" ng-change="onChnage()" class='checkbox'>
```

JS

```
$scope.onChnage = function(){
    if($scope.index == true){
        $scope.indexonClick();
    } else if($scope.aggs == true){
        $scope.aggsonClick();
    } else if($scope.index == false){
        console.log('false');
    }
};

$scope.indexonClick = function(){
    alert('index Clicked!');
}

$scope.aggsonClick = function(){
    alert('aggs Clicked!');
};
```

Comment: where do you have `$scope.index` and what you exactly need in the ans?

Comment: But why exactly do you need to know the name of the row?

Comment: I need to know if ng-model is true or false because on that value I would like to execute another function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pls check this code,

```js
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  

  $scope.tableData = [{
    name: 'Index',
    url: '#',
    valueMain: 12,
    tValue: 13,
    model: 'index',
    subvalues: [{
      name: 'Keys',
      url: '#',
      valueSub: 544,
      tValue: 67
    }, {
      name: 'Leaders',
      url: '#',
      valueSub: 67,
      tValue: 89
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'Aggregators',
    url: '#',
    valueMain: 78,
    tValue: 91,
    model: 'aggs',
    subvalues: [{
      name: 'TPM',
      url: '#',
      valueSub: 11,
      tValue: 13
    }, {
      name: 'Pollster',
      url: '#',
      valueSub: 23,
      tValue: 45
    }]

  }];
  
  
  $scope.onChnage = function(value,test){
    console.log(test)
    if(value.model=='index'){
      $scope.indexonClick(test)
    } else if(value.model=='aggs'){
      $scope.aggsonClick(test)
    } else if($scope.index==false){
      console.log('false')
    }
  };
  
  $scope.indexonClick= function(test){
    var value = (test == true ? 'clicked' : 'un clicked')
    alert('index ' + value)
  }
  
  $scope.aggsonClick = function(test){
    var value = (test == true ? 'clicked' : 'un clicked')
     alert('aggs ' + value)
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.20"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <table class='table'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
         
        <th>name</th>
        <th>itemOne</th>
        <th>itemTwo</th>
        <th>model</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="value in tableData| orderBy:'-valueMain'">
      <tr>
       
        <td>
          <button ng-show="value.expand" ng-click='value.expand = false'>-</button>
          <button ng-show="!value.expand" ng-click='value.expand = true'>+</button>
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="test" ng-change="onChnage(value,test)" class='checkbox'
>
          <a rel="noopener" target="_blank" href={{value.url}}>
  {{value.name}}
  </a>
        </td>
        <td>{{value.valueMain}}</td>
        <td>{{value.tValue}}</td>
        <td>{{value.model}}</td>
        <tr>
          <tr ng-show="value.expand" ng-repeat="subs in value.subvalues| orderBy:'-valueSub'" >
            <td>
              {{subs.name}}
            </td>
            <td>
              {{subs.valueSub}}
            </td>
            <td>
              {{subs.tValue}}
            </td>
             
          </tr>
        </tr>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

**`Pls run this code snippet`**

[Here is the plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/xyRxybe5fZv66sJYPqhG?p=preview)

Comment: Hi Thank you for your answer I am just thinking why does this just runs once? that is when I open the page for the first time and click on the checkboxses it shows the akert values but if I uncheck and then check it it does not show the value?

Comment: @imi, check now, both the answer and plunker are updated.

Comment: Thanks it works but I still have one question what if I was to unclick the checkboyx right now I dont get any value, if I want to console.log something uique to each checkbox when the checkbox was unchecked

Comment: @Imi, is that what you needed?

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite the function you call so it gets its `row` as an argument:

```
... ng-change="onChange(data)" ...
```

... then use the provided row as source of info:

```
$scope.onChange = function(row){
  alert(row.name); // Aggregators or Index
};
```

[Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/wNaehaB8DYJxpe6cjcMt?p=preview). As a sidenote, I'd strongly recommend using `console.log` instead of `alert`.

Comment: "**As a sidenote, I'd strongly recommend using console.log instead of alert.**": so why did you use `alert()`?

Comment: Because it was in the original post, and I don't know the intentions of its author. In general, yes, `console` is a much better servant.

Comment: @raina77ow: but I want to get the value of ng-model because i want to execute another function based on if the checkbox is clicked or not

Comment: Then either pass `data.model` directly (as in @MattWay's answer), or extract it inside the function (`if (row.model) { ... }`). BTW, instead of `ng-change` you may just as well listen to data.model changes directly.

Comment: @raina77ow how can I listen to the data model directly?

Comment: Yet again depends on what you want to do: any component using `data.model` as an expression listens for its changes automatically. If you want something extra, use $scope.$watch either on a separate controller, or on all the elements of the collection(check [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20024156/how-to-watch-changes-on-models-created-by-ng-repeat) for details).

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is pass the value into your `onChnage()` function. For example:

```
<input ... ng-change="onChnage(data.model)" ... />
```

*Notice that you are now providing the current value of checkbox to the onchange function*.

```
$scope.onChnage = function(isChecked){
    console.log(isChecked);

    ...
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer I tried this approach before but the problem is that I want the values of each checkbox when checked and unchecked because I want to manipulate DOM elements corresponding to these check boxes when checked and unchecked

Comment: Could you be more specific about "I want to manipulate DOM elements"?

Comment: supose checkbox index is clicked i shows a series of values unique to index and when it is unchecked is hides the series when checkbox aggs is checked it shows the series unique to aggregators and when it is unchecked it hides the series

Comment: Why are you doing it this way at all then? Why not use ng-show for example?

Comment: ng-show only takes boolean while I need to call a functions hide() and show() also I need to spicify which series to hide or show.

Comment: This is exactly what you use ng-show for. You set it to the checked state of the box inside your series wrapper. You should never manipulate dom directly in angular.

Answer (score 1):

Pass your input to your function

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="data.model" 
  ng-change="onChnage(data.model)" class='checkbox'>
```

partly solved plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/aTo8FsMo5hgTGc2TM5Dx?p=preview

Comment: using double curly braces return a string not the real object. it should be without braces...

Comment: Oops, i missed it. corrected it now. thanks for that @PoyrazYilmaz

Comment: thank you pandian but I want the checked and unchecked values of all the checkboxses